# After click on datepicker make input stay active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out a problem that arises when you click on the input where the bootstrap datepicker is displayed and after clicking on the day the input fills correctly but the label goes back to the bottom.

But after the second click on the input, the label stays up.

I don't know how to make this mistake.

Thank you all in advance for your help and answer.

```js
$('.form-group').each((i, e) => {
  $('.form-control', e)
    .focus(function() {
      e.classList.add('not-empty');
    })
    .blur(function() {
      this.value === '' ? e.classList.remove('not-empty') : null;
    });
});
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
  format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
  calendarWeeks: true,
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true
});
```

```css
/* === Form Control === */

.form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-group input {
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.form-group input:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.form-group>.lForm-label {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #9C9AB3;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
  transform: scale(1.4);
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.form-group input {
  width: 100%;
}

.form-group>.lForm-label {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4) translateY(20px);
  transform: scale(1.4) translateY(20px);
}

.form-group.not-empty>.lForm-label {
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
}

.form-group input {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9C9AB3;
}

.form-group input::placeholder:hover {
  display: none !important;
}

.form-group input,
.form-group input:focus,
.form-group input:focus:hover {
  color: #9C9AB3;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
}

.form-group input:focus,
.form-group input:focus:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fdd365;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.en-CA.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="birthDateId" class="form-control-label lForm-label">Date of birth</label>
  <div id="sandbox-container">
    <input type="text" name="dateofbirth" id="birthDateId" class="form-control" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be better if you handle add/remove Class by using [datePicker Events](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html)

Check this example

```js
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
  format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
  calendarWeeks: true,
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true
}).on('show', function(e) {
  $(this).parents(".form-group").addClass('not-empty')
}).on('hide', function(e) {
  if(!$(this).val())
    $(this).parents(".form-group").removeClass('not-empty')
});
```

```css
/* === Form Control === */

.form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-group input {
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.form-group input:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.form-group>.lForm-label {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #9C9AB3;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
  transform: scale(1.4);
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.form-group input {
  width: 100%;
}

.form-group>.lForm-label {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4) translateY(20px);
  transform: scale(1.4) translateY(20px);
}

.form-group.not-empty>.lForm-label {
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
}

.form-group input {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9C9AB3;
}

.form-group input::placeholder:hover {
  display: none !important;
}

.form-group input,
.form-group input:focus,
.form-group input:focus:hover {
  color: #9C9AB3;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
}

.form-group input:focus,
.form-group input:focus:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fdd365;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.en-CA.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="birthDateId" class="form-control-label lForm-label">Date of birth</label>
  <div id="sandbox-container">
    <input type="text" name="dateofbirth" id="birthDateId" class="form-control" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ahmer El-sayed Thank you for your reply and help ... yes this post resolved my problem but I forgot to add that I have more inputs than for example username or password

Comment: there is no problem because `this` is related to the element which you clicked , so no need to make for loop to add/remove class

Comment: but look , here i add class on the parent class `form-group` so if you have more than one item inside this class you have to change the target parent class here

Comment: i see that there is no issue if you have more than one input with its right container class `form-group` , what's the problem exactly ?

Comment: I will try to describe it as follows: I have a form with email,pass,username atc .... and of course date of birth.
All the inputs use the scripts I added here ... If I click and fill in the email or pass or username label it will stay up .. of course if the input is empty the label comes back to the bottom that's all right ... The problem occurs when clicking on the date birth where I click in the datepicker label does not stay up but goes back to the bottom, but if I click on that input again the label stays up.

Comment: aha, i got it . Okay you can re-use the same `forEach` function on your original code with the datepicker function which i did , also you can define a new class insted of `form-group` and forloop for other elements which doesn't use datepicker

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know exactly what you mean ....I'm not very good at JS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209363/discussion-between-ahmed-el-sayed-and-syntaxeen).

Answer (score 0):

You have a timing-problem. On-Blur the input-value is not set yet. Better use the [hide-event provided by bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html) like so:

```js
$('.form-group').each((i, e) => {
  $('.form-control', e)
    .focus(function() {
      e.classList.add('not-empty');
    })
    .blur(function() {

      //this.value === '' ? e.classList.remove('not-empty') : null;

    });
});
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
  format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
  calendarWeeks: true,
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true
}).on('hide', function (ev) {
  if(ev.target.value === '') 
    $(ev.target).parents('.form-group').removeClass('not-empty') 
})
```

```css
/* === Form Control === */

.form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-group input {
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.form-group input:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.form-group>.lForm-label {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #9C9AB3;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
  transform: scale(1.4);
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.form-group input {
  width: 100%;
}

.form-group>.lForm-label {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4) translateY(20px);
  transform: scale(1.4) translateY(20px);
}

.form-group.not-empty>.lForm-label {
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
}

.form-group input {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9C9AB3;
}

.form-group input::placeholder:hover {
  display: none !important;
}

.form-group input,
.form-group input:focus,
.form-group input:focus:hover {
  color: #9C9AB3;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
}

.form-group input:focus,
.form-group input:focus:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fdd365;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.en-CA.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="birthDateId" class="form-control-label lForm-label">Date of birth</label>
  <div id="sandbox-container">
    <input type="text" name="dateofbirth" id="birthDateId" class="form-control" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```